# Plotting fewer wind barbs in NorthPolarStereo projection in python

Tags: python, cartopy

I want to plot maps for sea level pressure and wind using the NorthPolarStereo projection. I managed to plot the pressure in contours and the windbarbs, but I can't adjust the wind barbs in any way. When plotting it in PlateCaree projection, I can plot every second lat/lon for u and v, which thinned out the wind barb field. However, the same method does not work for this projection and I don't know why.

Below is the part of my code that I use to plot the sea level + wind map and that won't let me alter the wind barbs:

```
vcs=np.arange(-3,3.2,0.2)
slplevels=[980,985,990,995,1000, 1005, 1010, 1015,1020, 1025,1030,1035]

ax3 = plt.subplot(4,2,3, projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
ax3.set_extent([coord_east, coord_west, coord_south, coord_north], crs.PlateCarree())
ax3.coastlines(linewidth=1.5)

data, lon = add_cyclic_point(slp_2, slp_2['lon'])
      
slp2=ax3.contourf(lon,slp_2["lat"][:], data/100, levels=vcs,
            transform = data_crs, extend='both', cmap=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm'))


ax3.barbs(u10_2['lon'][::2].values, u10_2['lat'][::2].values, u10_2[::2,::2].values, 
      v10_2[::2,::2].values, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), pivot='middle',
         sizes=dict(emptybarb=0.0000001, height=0.5),
         length=4, color='black', regrid_shape=35, 
      linewidth=1, alpha=0.8, barb_increments=dict(half=.5, full=1, flag=5))

stipples=ax3.contourf(slp_std_2['lon'][:], slp_std_2['lat'][:], 
                 slp_std_2[:,:]/100, colors='none', levels= np.arange(0.1,6,0.1), transform = data_crs,
                 hatches=['..']) 

sclim=ax3.contour(sc['lon'], sc['lat'], sc[:,:]/100, levels=slplevels,
          transform = data_crs, extend='both', colors='black', alpha=0.7)

plt.clabel(sclim, inline=1, fontsize=18, fmt='%1.0f',
                  colors='black')
       
cbar_slp = plt.colorbar(slp2, ax=ax3, ticks=[-3.0,-2.0,-1.0,0,1.0,2.0,3.0], extend='both', orientation='horizontal', fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
cbar_slp.ax.tick_params(labelsize=18)
cbar_slp.ax.set_xlabel('hPa', fontsize=18)
```

Comment: `ax3.barbs()` has options `regrid_shape` and `target_extent` to handle what you need.

Comment: Thanks! regrid_shape did the trick. I'm not sure how to set target_extent (I couldn't find documentation on it), but in this case I didn't need it.

Comment: Hi @Eveline, its better that you add the imports of your code, the error you get, and the output you want to have.